# I am trying to obtain a list of users who have a value set in 'orgTitle'

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am trying to obtain a list of users who have a value set in 'orgTitle'.

I am referencing the following documentation:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users

There does not seem to be any means to use the 'query' parameter of the list function to obtain the list of users who have a value set in 'orgTitle'.

I tried running with `users().list(query="orgTitle:'*'")`, but this returns all entries, including users who do not have any value set in title.

Further, I noticed that there is no field `orgTitle` in the response, and that there is organizations[].title.  Should I change my query to organizations.title instead?